# java casting ClassCastException

Tags: java, casting

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A implements C {
    ...
}

public abstract class B extends A {
    method();
}
```

But when I try to do the following

```
A a = null;
A a = new A();
((B) a).method();
```

I receive a ClassCastException, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The solution is don't do this as it makes no sense whatsoever. The a variable refers to an A object and you can't just cast it to a B and hope that wishing it were so would make it a B object. Why would you want to attempt this? What's the impetus behind this?

Comment: How you get a CCE is beyond me. You should fail at instantiating an instance of A - it is abstract and `new A()` is either a typo or you're just throwing questions around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

B extends A, but A doesnt extend B.

everything A has B has, but A cant do the stuff declared in B

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `B` is an instance of `A`, but an instance of `A` is not necessarily a `B`. Similar to saying "all circles are shapes, but not all shapes are circles".

You can't do what you are trying to do. That's why you get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is a constructor to take and A object and make a larger B object out of it which has the included method (which A does not have). But that doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Cant think for the life of me why you would want to do this in practice, and wouldn't just build the B object to start with.

```
public abstract class A implements C {
    ...
}

public abstract class B extends A {

    public B(A child){
        //Construct a B out of A here
    }

    public void method();
}
```

Then

```
 A a = null;
 A a = new A();
 new B(a).method();
```